# Timepicker pick option in dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I have a problem with timepicker V4. In dropdown there is a de- and increment option and pick option where you can pick an hour or a minute. In my case when I pick minutes the option is empty.

[image]
[image]

Why aren't there any minutes to pick? Disabling pick option is also a possibility but I haven't found in the documentation or in google results any settings for this. Console also doesn't return any errors.

I know there is a newer version out there but currently I cannot update. Have to find a solution for this.

This is my code

```
<input  type='text' name='somename' class='form-control' />"
   <span class='input-group-addon' >"
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>"
   </span>
```

Initialization should not be a problem. The hour picker works fine.

[image]

UPDATE

This is NOT a solution. It is just a workaround but it works for us. If you use `debug:true` you can inspect a popup. You can then see the classes or ids and with this you can disable click on hours and/or minutes picker.

```
$('yourPickerIdOrClass').click(function () {
                $(this).find(".timepicker .timepicker-hour").removeAttr("data-action").css("cursor", "default");
                $(this).find(".timepicker .timepicker-minute").removeAttr("data-action").css("cursor", "default");
            });
```

Comment: You didn't mention which version you're using, and you didn't show us any code.  So all we can do is guess.  I'm guessing you're using v4, and that your code does not look like the working example code: https://getdatepicker.com/4/

Comment: Sorry, I thought if I choose B3, V4 will be self explainable. Yes I am using V4 and I've updated my issue. Thank you!

Comment: From what we can see in the screenshots, it looks like you are using multiple pickers, or at least with date, hour and minutes split out into different pickers?  Maybe with DE locale.  Maybe with customised displays (eg all hours displayed at once on a single panel)? Again guessing bcs I have nothing else to go on there must be something in the setup/instantiation of those which is not working.  It is hard to do anything other than speculate without a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I understand, can picker in dropdown be at least disabled so that only increasing and decreasing is active?